Существует ли способ получить с помощью API Росреестра кадастровый номер по координатам точки
Имеется база данных полигональных объектов, стоит задача определить, какие кадастровые номера попадают в границы этих объектов. Визуальное сопоставление границ каждого объекта с кадастровой картой требует много времени, поэтому возникла идея как-то автоматизировать данный процесс: например, вычислить заранее координаты центроидов анализируемых полигональных объектов и при помощи API Росреестра (или какого-нибудь другого аналогичного сервиса) определить, к каким кадастровым номерам относится каждый центроид.
Имеется ли такая возможность?

На апи росреестра не замечал такой возможности.
Я выкачивал все кадастровые номера своего квартала (перебором) в базу через открытый апи и потом там искал что нужно.
Для поиска объектов с адресной частью можно скачать классификатор ГАР.
На публичной кадастровой карте есть апи для поиска по клику на карте. Можно попробовать спарсить через него.

нашел сейчас библиотеку https://github.com/GregEremeev/rosreestr-api, по ней разобрался с форматом URL для нужного мне API-запроса. Если, например, у меня есть такие координаты: [53,4414911212154 81,9705921770956], то API-запрос будет таким: https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/1?text=53.4414911212154%2081.9705921770956&limit=11&tolerance=2
Но меня смущает, что базовый URL у неё https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api, хотя, если я правильно понял, актуальным является https://rosreestr.gov.ru/api, но он мой запрос в таком приведенном мной формате уже не отрабатывает.

pkk это карта, это разные сервисы, карта отдельно, апи отдельно
